# Using react.js with custom native DOM events

Tags: reactjs

How do you access native dom events with react?

The [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) says "If you find that you need the underlying browser event for some reason, simply use the **nativeEvent** attribute to get it.

How do you use the nativeEvent attribute?

I tried onDelete={this.handleDelete} but it doesn't seem to get triggered. I can bind the event with jQuery so I know it's firing.

Comment: `nativeEvent` only exists if the event is a standard DOM event and is one of the [supported events in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#supported-events).

Answer (score 1):

React doesn't support custom DOM events.  You have two options:

- use a [regular event emitter](https://www.npmjs.org/package/events)
- add custom event handlers using jQuery

Either of these should be wrapped into a mixin, and don't forget to remove the listeners in componentWillUnmount.  The jQuery option is a last resort.